# How to configure secure fake port on tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat

I have an application that runs on secure channel, I want to configure a secure port. I am adding following connector into my tomcat server.xml file

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
       maxThreads="150" secure="true"
       clientAuth="false" />
```

It connects to server when I hit

```
https://localhost.com:8443
```

in browser, but I never get response back, it connects to server forever.

I would really appreciate any help on this.

Thanks.

Comment: What does 'fake' have to do with it?

Comment: By fake I mean I don't want certificates or encryption but I want channel to be secure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue was due to a webservice was down that my application is depend upon, that is why  request were stuck forever.

However the above configuration for configuring fake secure port worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you configuration is not complete. Take a look at this tutorial:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html

It has to look more like this:

```
<Connector
       protocol="HTTP/1.1"
       port="8443" maxThreads="200"
       scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
       keystoreFile="${user.home}/.keystore" keystorePass="changeit"
       clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

Without `SSLEnabled="true"` there will be no encryption.

Comment: Thanks Christian, I did the same but request to server from browser stuck forever. However I deployed other test app it worked fine on https.